# Should I use "fd == -1" or "fd < 0" to test for invalid file descriptor?

Tags: posix, file-descriptor

If I have a function that accepts a file descriptor and it wants to defensively check that the fd is valid, should it check via `if (fd >= 0) {...}` or `if (fd != -1) {...}`? Linux syscalls like [open(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) and [dup(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) all appear to return -1 on failure, and most code I've seen initializes fds to -1 before use.

Am I right that there are no meaningful negative fd values except -1? Rejecting all negative fds seems more robust, but is that just propagating a misunderstanding that a large negative fd is expected?

Comment: A friend pointed out that Postel's law suggests "fd < 0". But OTOH https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-thomson-postel-was-wrong-03.html suggests "fd == -1"

Answer (score 1):

[POSIX file descriptors are non-negative integers.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_166)  Even -1 is not valid as a file descriptor.  And not all functions creating new file descriptors return a non-file descriptor -1 in case of error—[`pipe`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) is a counterexample that does *not* use this kind of in-band signaling.

I tend to use comparisons against zero instead of -1 mainly because they result in slightly more compact machine code.  (This applies to error return values and situations where -1 is used to denote the absence of an open file descriptor.) The compiler usually cannot make the transformation on its own.  Most architectures can perform a (signed) comparison of a register against zero more efficiently than a comparison against -1.  Some have combined test-and-branch instructions for zero values, or they can perform the comparison without clobbering a register or encoding the constant in the instruction.

Comment: The pipe() link you included says "On success, zero is returned.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately." and "pipe() does not modify pipefd on failure." so I think it is not in fact a counterexample because it never sets the fd to a negative number less than -1. Have I misunderstood you point?

Comment: What I meant is that the return value is not used for error reporting *and* the file descriptor on success.

Comment: The part of your answer about comparing against 0 vs -1 is true, but IMO completely misplaced in this answer. I think it creates the wrong impression, i.e. that the difference would be in the same ballpark as the cost of any IO function.

Comment: Please do not compare with 0. A fd value of 0 is a valid fd and you get that if the program closes stdin. Have seen bugs like this in pretty popular libraries like iotcore. Just no. Trust me, my colleagues, and the week we spent digging for this bug. Comparing fd <0 is the proper thing to do.

Comment: You say that file descriptors are non-negative integers, and then you go against your own answer by saying you compare to 0 (a non-negative integer) to check if fd is invalid. Even if comparing to 0 was correct (which it isn't, it is a valid fd), doing so just to have slightly more compact binary smells like an unreasonable case of premature optimization - every file operation I can think of is orders of magnitude more expensive than the most inefficient way to compare two ints compiler could generate. This would be a fine answer if you removed the second paragraph.